# Array indexing in pytorch

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch

I am experiencing weird behavior while dealing with the following scenario. tne is the batch size, while N is the total number of possible locations for each example. Each example has exactly 24 scalar outputs, where their locations are stored in dof tensor (size of dof is (tne X 24)). Fint_e has a size of tneX24 (i.e., the 24 outputs for each example). I am trying to construct a large tensor, which has a size of tne X N. When I do the following, it fills in the wrong manner. Any advice?

```
Fint_MAT        = torch.zeros((tne,N))
Fint_MAT[:,dof]  = Fint_e
```

The dof tensor, which has the size of batch size X 24, has different indices for each example, but each example has in total 24 indices.

For instance,

dof[0,:] = 0, 1, 6, 9, … (24 in total)

dof[1,:] = 1,100, 151, 300,… (24 in total)

Any hint would be appreciated.

I include below a simple scenario for better elaboration:

```
tne = 3
N   = 48
Fint_MAT = torch.zeros((tne,N))
Fint_e   = torch.randn((tne, 24))
v1 = torch.arange(24).unsqueeze(0)
v2 = torch.arange(12, 36).unsqueeze(0)
v3 = torch.arange(24, 48).unsqueeze(0)
dof      = torch.cat((v1,v2,v3), axis=0).long()
Fint_MAT[:,dof]  = Fint_e
```

Comment: My advice in situations like this is to look at the shape attribute of every variable involved in the assignment, i.e. `FintMat.shape`, `dof[:,:,24].shape`, `Fint_MAT[:,dof[:,:24]].shape`, `Fint_e[:,:24].shape`. Are all of the shapes what you would expect them to be? Also remember if `dof` is batch_size x 24, `dof[:, :24]` is the whole tensor. The index doesn't slice anything off because its the maximum size.

Comment: However, if you want more detailed advice, you'll need to provide a [MCVE]. Including an example input and output.

Comment: @Cecilia, thanks for the reply. I have added an example, as you suggested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by fills in the wrong manner? When I run your example, I get a matrix Fint_MAT with a copy of [Fint_e[0, :], Fint_e[2, :] ] in each row. What is your desired output?

Comment: @Cecilia, I am expecting each row in Fint_MAT to have 24 zeros and 24 nonzeros in the example mentioned above, but what I get is that all the 48 entries are nonzero.

Comment: For your final line of your example, try `Fint_MAT[:, :24] = Fint_e`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Cecilia, Not exactly. Each row would have 24 nonzeros and 24 zeros, while they are different from one row to another. The columns of the nonzeros are stated in the tensor dof for each corresponding row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the key here is to use pairs of indices. Your `dof` tensor indexes the columns, but you also need to index the rows.

```
x_index = torch.arange(3).unsqueeze(1).expand(3, 24)
```

`x_index` is a 3 x 24 tensor where each row is the row index. Now you can use this together with the `dof` tensor to index elements in the `Fint_MAT` matrix

```
Fint_MAT[x_index, dof] = Fint_e
```

Basically, corresponding elements in `x_index` and `dof` form a [row, column] pair in `Fint_MAT`, so `Fint_MAT[x_index[0], dof[0]]= Fint_e[0]` etc.

I think this should give you what you want.